# Installing PyGame on windows7 (I5, 64 bit) anyone have a link for a easy installer?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, installation, pygame

Good Morning,

I am not understanding the tutorials that are online for installing PyGame.  does anyone know of website that has an .exe file that I just click on and it will do all the installation for me?  Any help is appreciated, I have spent all morning just trying to get the pygame into python :(  * Note I would be willing to uninstall python and start from scratch if that is a good idea.

Thank you

Comment: try opening `cmd.exe` and installing pygame by typing in `python -m pip install pygame` and pressing enter. After installing it this way, close and reopen whatever IDE or console you're running python in and try running `import pygame`. If there are no errors when your script is  that one line, then it's installed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  That did not work for me a lil too advanced.  I need a point and click solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest version of PyGame from their downloads page:

http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

This lists downloads for all platforms, including Windows installer (.msi) packages. Just download the version you need and double-click to run it (note that they currently recommend using a 32-bit Python installation for compatibility if you are on 64-bit Windows).

Alternatively, you can install the Wheel package for PyGame using the pip package manager, which will also make updating PyGame easier in the future. Installation using this method is also described on the above page, and a link to the package on PyPI is located here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygame/1.9.3

Comment: Thanks Christopher.  I guess I need to uninstall the 64 bit version I have :(
 Ok I am going to nuke my installation and try to start over.